# Bootstrap 4 grid issue only on Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I made a whole website using Bootstrap 4. Now I noticed that if number of columns in a row is equal to 12 every column start in a new line instead of wrapping to previous. When number of columns is smaller (like 10) there is no problem. This looks like a flexbug#11 but when I'm trying to set border 1px or set flex-basis to the columns problem still occurs.

Problem disappears when I'm setting little lower flex-basis like 49.9% instead of 50% to the col-6, but I think that isn't right way to solve this problem, because this not working in all sections.

Have you another way to fix this bug? Do you need more information from me? Thanks for help!

Header sample:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="ccfw-site-logo">
        <a href="/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home">
          <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logo.png" srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/logo@2x.png 2x" alt="etrose logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="ccfw-primary-nav clearfix">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#onas"><span>About us</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#wartosci"><span>Our vision</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/uslugi"><span>Services</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/praca"><span>Job offers</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/kontakt"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And screenshots from Chrome and Safari:
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you ask. Provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue, or else no one can give a proper answer.

Comment: Please provide some code and specialty if you override Bootstrap

Comment: I am using original bootstrap styles, I am not overriding. It's a simple grid with bootstrap columns.

Comment: The problem is your logo size. Is it a responsive image? Try reducing its width and it should fix the issue.

Comment: But is not only problem with header. This problem is in all sections, where the number of columns equal 12. Header is only example. Logo isn't generate this problem, I tried reducing width with no success.
https://imgur.com/a/quQEV

Comment: send live site link

Comment: https://en.etrose.com/

Answer (score 1):

Probably related to this: [Bootstrap 4 Safari on Mac Grid issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403391/bootstrap-4-safari-on-mac-grid-issue)

the problem seems to be how safari handles the `.row:after, .row:before{display:table;}`
causing the `.col`s inside the `.row` to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

replace css old code to  this code

```
.ccfw-site-logo a {
line-height: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: This change do nothing to fix problem with columns wrapping on Safari.

Comment: .ccfw-site-logo a {
line-height: unset !important;
}

remove and used

.ccfw-site-logo a {
line-height: normal !important;
}

Comment: Like I wrote before - this change not fixing my problem. Logo is not problem here.
This problem appears in all sections with 12 columns - not only in header, so logo do nothing wrong here.