# Bootstrap 4 Safari on Mac Grid issue

Tags: safari, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

There is an issue with Bootstrap 4 and Safari brower on Mac.
When using cols inside a row it breaks it, and doesn't work like on firefox or chrome. I'm using a simple code like this:

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 hidden-xs align_left"><h3>TEXT</h3></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">TEXT</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">TEXT</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying different 'fix codes' from another questions but they doesn't solve the problem. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fixed All Bootstrap 4 issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Finally solved the problem with this simple CSS:

```
.row:before, .row:after {display: none !important;}
```

It seems there is some code hidden in :before and :after elements inside the rows. This causes some kind of issues in safari browsers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling for hours to get this to work. Finally got it!!

Comment: Thank you I was struggling with this issue, .row:after and .row:before are suppose to clear floats. its same attr as clearfix class.

Comment: This fixed a similar issue I was having in Bootstrap 3 as well, thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know why this works on mobile safari? Seems like a massive over-sight.

Comment: Hello, does anyone know how to fix in bootstrap version 3? because setting display to none breaks the layout everywhere.

Comment: This is utterly perplexing behavior. My columns layouts usually equal 12 per row, so easy call to remove, but really odd fix--just for ipad!

Comment: Praise the Hive Mind!

Comment: Solved it!! Thanks man

Answer (score 9):

```
.row:before, .row:after {width:0px; height:0px;}
```

There is a reason for display:table before and after row.
By using display:none, the row will not preserve its height depending on the elements inside it, and row height is now 0px because the columns inside is floating..